# Select query with dates using Between not working correctly

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I have this select query:

```
SELECT field_1, field_2, field_3, field_4
FROM MyTable
Where DateTimeField > '16/04/2013 00:00:00' ;
```

It returns me `all the rows`, even those before `16/04/2013`.

I also, tryed this:

```
SELECT dt_cadastro,descricao, projeto, funcionalidade
FROM chamados
Where dt_cadastro BETWEEN '16/04/2013 00:00:00' AND '28/05/2013 23:59:59';
```

Same results... =\

This i Tried on my MySql Manager.

When I try it on my application like:

```
string sql = @"SELECT proj.descricao AS projeto, func.descricao AS funcionalidade, clb.clube AS cliente, ch.descricao
         FROM chamados ch 
         INNER JOIN projetos proj ON ch.projeto = proj.id 
         INNER JOIN funcionalidades func ON ch.funcionalidade = func.id
         INNER JOIN clubes clb ON ch.clube = clb.id
         WHERE ch.dt_cadastro BETWEEN @dt_inicial AND @dt_final";
   MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
   cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
   cmd.CommandText = sql;
   cmd.Parameter.Add(new MySqlParameter("@dt_inicial", MySqlDbType.DateTime)).Value = dt1
   cmd.Parameter.Add(new MySqlParameter("@dt_final", MySqlDbType.DateTime)).Value = dt2
```

Then I assign the result of this query to a `DataSet`.
But the `DataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count` is always `< 0`.

It all were working, but since I changed my `Visual Studio 2010` to the `VS 2012` everything started to goes wrong =\

**UPDATE**

It worked both `MySql manager` and in `my application`. Like this:

```
SELECT proj.descricao AS projeto, func.descricao AS funcionalidade, clb.clube AS cliente, ch.descricao
            FROM chamados ch 
            INNER JOIN projetos proj ON ch.projeto = proj.id 
            INNER JOIN funcionalidades func ON ch.funcionalidade = func.id
            INNER JOIN clubes clb ON ch.clube = clb.id
            WHERE ch.dt_cadastro BETWEEN '2013/04/28' AND '2013/05/28'
```

But it's not working when I try to put time with it like (hh:mm:ss, e.g 23:59:59).
its ok though.
And I always used,

```
MySqlCommand.Parameter.Add(new MySqlParameter("@date1", MySqlDbType.DateTime)).value = xxx
```

and always worked. I'll get the date in the `dd/mm/yyyy` format. Always worked, now what may I do ? The variable `xxx` above, was `string`, because I need to add `hh:mm:ss`. I changed this for `DateTime` variable and worked... o.O Why it used to work the way I did  but now it no longer works.

**UPDATE 2**
I've Found out the problem.
I have NO IDEA why of this, so if anyone could explain to me the reason, I'd appreciate !
I was using `string` variable type to pass in my `MySqlCommand.Parameter`.
I changed the type to `DateTime` and Worked... Have no ideia why it stopped to work the way it was at first place. But now it's working. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT dt_cadastro,descricao, projeto, funcionalidade
FROM chamados
Where dt_cadastro BETWEEN CONVERT('16/04/2013 00:00:00', DATETIME) AND
CONVERT('28/05/2013 23:59:59', DATETIME);
```

Comment: I tried this, now I get NO RESULTS at all...
I don't think it's a problem of conversion, because when I using `MySqlCommand.Paramter.Add...` it's already doing this. Or not ?

Comment: what is the type of 'dt_cadastro' column? Timestamp?

Comment: it's strange. i tried that query with Timestamp and with Datetime too, but i got the correct resultset.

Comment: Omg, its demonic then u.u  what do you think it could be ? Maybe MySqlVersion ? Its an old one ;x  
I also tried to restart mysql service, but still the same... I can't understand the error, it were working perfect. I change my computer and changed the VS2010 to VS2012 then everything started to bug u.u obs: This dataset I'm trying to fill a reportviewer, does it make difference?

Answer (score 0):

Please give this a try:

```
SELECT dt_cadastro,descricao, projeto, funcionalidade
FROM chamados
Where dt_cadastro BETWEEN '2013-04-16' AND '2013-05-28';
```

Comment: Again, it returned me `all the rows` ;\

Comment: How many records are in the table and how many records is this query supposed to return? Also, please check the least date and max date in your records.

Comment: I already did. There are `24 records`. The dates are from ´15/04/2013` to `08/05/2013`.

Comment: That's weird! If you run this query in MySQL directly, does it return selected records? Or is it returning all records?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, did you follow date format in query as `yyyy-mm-dd` as is my example or like `dd/mm/yyyy` as in yours?

Comment: AS mine, `dd/mm/yyyy` as I use `parameters` it will do the conversion automatically, or I'm wrong? I think its right, because it always worked ! But since I changed to VS2012 and updated the `.NEt Connector` things started to go wrong u.u

Comment: `.Net connectors` should automatically convert to specified formats. But I have my doubts and would double check if I change even a tiniest bit of framework. I can't recall if `.Net` logs SQL queries, if it does, then I suggest that you check what query this code generated and try to run it directly in `MySQL`. Let us know of your findings.

Comment: Obs: If I try the select with `BETWEEN '2013/04/01' AND '2013/05/28'` its working ;x On my MySql manager.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM po_header WHERE (STR_TO_DATE(date_format(PO_DATE, '%d/%m/%Y'), '%d/%m/%Y %T') BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE(@param1, '%d/%m/%Y %T') AND STR_TO_DATE(@param2, '%d/%m/%Y %T'))
```

I know this maybe looking mess and weird but it work, I've tried to make it shorter but it doesn't work PO_DATE is column Date in MySql
and it works fine with DataSource's Fill